# JointJS Inspector without Rappid

Tags: jointjs, rappid

I'm looking to create an inspector like that available in Rappid.  Unfortunately, I don't have money lying around to just buy Rappid... so I was hoping to make the inspector in pure JointJs.  I've tried looking around for ideas on where to start, but I can't seem to find anything useful.  Does anyone know a method of creating an inspector similar to that in Rappid?

Comment: It's a two way binding between an object to the form (ie., inspector, there are custom filters and custom theming as part of the package). However if you're looking for a drop in replacement (such as a library) then I don't think there's any in the wild. However you could try to build one upon [something like this](http://software-workshop.eu/content/binding-object-form-using-jquery)